# Binary search over a list of pairs

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

I need to find `elem` that would match `element`.
My program works but it is not efficient. I have a very large `ArrayList<Obj> pairs` (more than 4000 elements) and I use a binary search to find matching indexes.

```
public int search(String element) {
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
      list.add(pairs.get(i).getElem());
  }
  return index = Collections.binarySearch(list, element);
}
```

I wonder if there is a more efficient way than using a loop to copy half of the ArrayList pairs into a new ArrayList list. 
Constructor for Obj: `Obj x = new Obj(String elem, String word);`

Comment: Yes - the more efficient way is to write binary search for your pair list yourself and not create a copy of your list every single time you call search()

Comment: Use the *other* [`binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-) method, and provide a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to compare the list elements directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is solved.
As my issue was that ArrayList pairs type was `Obj` and `element` type was String, I couldn't use Collections.binarySearch, I decided to create a new variable 
`Obj x = new Obj(element, "");`. It looks like the string doesn't cause any issues (it passed my JUnit tests) as my `compareTo` method compares two `elem`s and ignores the second variable of `Obj x`.

My updated method:

```
public int search(String element) {
  Obj x = new Obj(element, "");
  int index = Collections.binarySearch(pairs, x);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your master list (`pairs`) does not change then I'd recommend creating a `TreeMap` to maintain reverse `index` structure, e.g.:

```
List<String> pairs = new ArrayList<String>(); //list containing 4000 entries

Map<String, Integer> indexMap = new TreeMap<>();

int index = 0;
for(String element : pairs){
    indexMap.put(element, index++);
}
```

Now, while searching for an element, all you need to do is :

```
indexMap.get(element);
```

That will give you the required `index` or `null` if element doesn't exist. Also, if an element can be present in the list multiple times then, you can change the `indexMap` to be `Map<String, List<Integer>>`.

Your current algorithm iterates the list and calls the binary search, so complexity would be `O(n)` for iteration and `O(log n)` whereas `TreeMap` guarantees `log(n)` time cost so it will be much quicker.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)'s the documentation of `TreeMap`.